# Present perfect or past simple for asking about a current problem that came from something in the past

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Shall I say

- > Has anyone who bought the record the same problem
- > Has anyone who've bought the record the same problem

I think present perfect fits better because the problem is now and the problem comes from the record.

Comment: You occasionally still find lexical (that is, not auxiliary) *have* inverting with its subject in questions and negations, but this has been growing increasingly rare for centuries now; I recommend treating *have* like other lexical verbs and employing *do* support when there's no other auxiliary in play: "**Does** anyone who bought the record **have** the same problem?"

Comment: But if at the time of writing people are still buying this record, can I use present perfect

Comment: Sure you can use the PrPf: "Has anyone who bought the record had the same problem?" It doesn't matter whether it's still being bought or not; this perfect involves anybody who ever bought it.

Comment: present perfect for buy  not for have   Has anyone who has bought the record had the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The present perfect sounds best to me, although it should be "who has" instead of "who have" or "who've" since "anyone" is singular.

Also, a more natural way to say this is "Does anyone who has bought the record have the same problem?"

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is correct, except that it is missing a word:

Has anyone who bought the record **had** the same problem

They bought the record before you, so their initial experience is in the past, so they **had** the problem. They may still be experiencing the problem, or they may have taken it back or thrown it away, but that is not of interest to you in asking the question.

Comment: I don't agree when you say "they bought the record before me" but what is for sure is that to have the problem you must first buy the record .